# Converting Json String to DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have data in json format that I'm having troubles converting to DateTime to use within my rails app.

json data

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16 16:00:00": 24.2},{"2014-06-17 12:00:00": 30.2},{"2014-06-18 17:00:00": 42.9}]} etc
```

Controller

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@source.url).read)

dates = []
temps = []

@data['data'].each do |data|
 dates << data.keys
 temps << data.values
end 

datetime = DateTime.parse(dates).strftime("%Q")
```

Gives me

```
can't convert Array into String
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert into date time to use with Highcharts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse an array not a string, because `dates` is an array. Parse each of the dates separately:

```
dates.flatten.each do |date|
  datetime = DateTime.parse(date)
end
```

Comment: This works but it's going to leave you with `datetime` containing only the last date in the array. That doesn't seem useful but it's also not clear what end result the question is looking for. Maybe use `map` to create an array of all the dates as `DateTime`s?

Comment: @jonah, no, `datetime` will not even be set outside the `each` block.  You must do something with it inside the block.

Comment: @user3373464, I see why. You are pushing arrays into `dates`, so `dates` is an array of arrays. Try `dates.flatten.each...`

Comment: Got it! Had to : datetime << DateTime.parse(date) thanks for the help.